# Rails, Ruby classes / modules / namespaces confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I have a Rails model: `app/models/A.rb` -> `class A < ActiveRecord::Base`

Then I have: `app/services/a/b/c.rb` -> `class A::B::C`, where both `a` and `b` are folders. AFAIK, `app/<foldername>` is autoloaded, so that is not an issue.

And, finally, I have an module: `module B` (it is an external gem with this name).

If I attempt to do this: `A::B::C.new` it throws an error message: `toplevel constant ...  referenced by ...` (Don't remember exactly) - in other words, it does **NOT** work.

Other classes defined under `a` folder - work just fine. For example: `app/services/a/x.rb` (`class A::X`)

If I try `A::B`, I simply get to `B` (the gem), with a warning message (but it continues to work).

But, if I rename either `a` or `b` folder name (and class signatures of course) - it works just fine!

So,

1) Why is that? How does ruby handle all these classes, modules, namespaces, inclusions?

2) Is it possible to have everything working w/o renaming a single thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need an intermediate A::B declared in `a/b.rb` to properly define the module `A::B` before you reference it, or you can re-style your declaration in your final file.

For example:

```
# a/b/c.rb
class A::B::C
end
```

This depends on module or class A and A::B being defined *before* that file is loaded.

You can side-step this:

```
class A
  module B
    class C
    end
  end
end
```

That will force-declare all the intermediates. As this introduces a lot of indentation, a slightly less messy approach is:

```
class A
  module B
  end
end

class A::B::C
end
```

Of course, having an `a.rb` and `a/b.rb` with the appropriate intermediate declarations often helps avoid all of this.

Comment: There is no "b.rb" (as it is an external gem). There is only top-level signature: "module B". 
So how would I go about that?

Comment: Force-declare it in your `a/b/c.rb` file, or make `a/b/c.rb` force-`require` the original definition.

Comment: OK. I'll try. Also wanted to ask if this (my) approach actually pollutes class A? 
Is it so that everything is getting loaded to class A?

Comment: It's generally bad form to mix services and models in the same namespace chain, so I'd try and avoid doing that whenever possible. That is, all the components of a namespace chain should be in the same directory structure, not scattered about. A service and a model should only be related by interface, not necessarily namespace. Remember it is possible to use `import` to compose the final structure you want if convenience is an issue, or even set up aliases like `A::B = AService::B`.

Comment: OK. I'll test if your approach works or not (just interesting) but will definitely consider redoing this part, so that they would not share the same namespace! Thank you!

BTW, what is `import`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, meant to say `include`. That is the method for importing namespaces.

Comment: Ah, OK. Are there any articles that you would recommend in order to understand all this? :)

Comment: There's a couple of things at work here: The ActiveSupport auto-loader and how it tries to find things automatically for you based on namespace to expected filename mapping, and order of operations when it comes to declaring namespaces. It's mostly just experimenting to get a feel for how these play together. As for articles, I can't think of any off the top, but a good Ruby reference book does get into more detail.